# How come certain keywords are converted to tags (Java) while others are not? (Kotlin)?

Tags: discussion, bug

When I select Java as tag without the [] brackets it will automatically convert this to a tag and make this [Java]. Therefore going to the URL

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.

However, when doing the same steps on the Kotlin tag without the brackets it does not turn this into [Kotlin] and I am forwarded to the URL

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Kotlin

Is this a bug?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin shows all the tabs for me, what link are you using?

Comment: I have updated my question and description. Seems the keyword Java is converted to a tag of [Java] whereas the keyword Kotlin is not converted to [Kotlin] therefore making the filtering options different.

Comment: @Ivar ... How did I find the MSE one and not the MSO one /facepalm, can't delete answer now, F

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146311/why-are-search-queries-inconsistently-converted-into-tags):

> If a word is realized to be a tag which is among the top 60 tags for the site, search automatically converts it into a tag search instead of a search for that word.

Comment: (Note, from the comments on that MSE post the magic number may no longer be 60, however this explains the process behind the conversion)